# Como trazer o radio button checado com um resultado do Banco

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Parece uma coisa tão simples mas não está dando certo estou tentando trazer checado um radio button mas ele não traz nada marcado o dado está sendo retornado do banco já fiz o teste mas o radio não vem marcado.

Na minha view do Blade estou trazendo assim:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="colaborativa" value="1" {{isset($escola->colaborativa) == 1 ? 'checked' : '' }} required>Sim</label>

<label><input type="radio" name="colaborativa" value="0" {{isset($escola->colaborativa) == 0 ? 'checked' : '' }} required>Não</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem erro de PHP, o correto:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="colaborativa" value="1" {{isset($escola->colaborativa) && $escola->colaborativa == 1 ? 'checked' : '' }} required>Sim</label>

<label><input type="radio" name="colaborativa" value="0" {{isset($escola->colaborativa) && $escola->colaborativa == 0 ? 'checked' : '' }} required>Não</label>
```

Comment: Valeu Virgilio era isso mesmo nem me atentei a isso trampar de madrugada dá nisso rsrsrsrsrs