# Trazendo option do radio button pre selecionado via CakePhp

Tags: php, cakephp-3

Tenho o seguinte `Form` abaixo.

Se eu passar `checked=checked` ele traz a última opção selecionada.

Mas, eu quero por exemplo que a primeira opção seja pré selecionada, alguma dica/sugestão?

```
<?php 

echo "<label> Selecione o tipo de entrada</label>";
echo $this->Form->input('tipo', array(
     'type'   => 'radio',
     'before' => '<div ' . $style . '>',
     'separator' => '</div><div ' . $style . '>',
     'options' => array(
           'D' => $this->Html->image(
               "botoes/dinheiro.png", array(
                    "alt" => "Dinheiro", 
                    "title" => "Dinheiro", 
                    "style" => "height: 32px")),
           'P' => $this->Html->image(
               "botoes/porcento.png", array(
                    "alt" => "Porcentagem", 
                    "title" => "Porcentagem", 
                    "style" => "width: 28px")),
           'H' => $this->Html->image(
               "botoes/hora.png", array(
                    "alt" => "Hora", 
                    "title" => "Hora", 
                    "style" => "height: 32px"))),
     'id' => 'tipo', 
     'label' => 'Dinheiro/Porcento', 
     'style' => '', 
     'legend' => false, 
     'onclick' => "formular()", 
     'checked' => 'checked',
     'required'));

?>
```

> Não é duplicata de [Como trazer o radio button checado com um resultado do Banco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156520/como-trazer-o-radio-button-checado-com-um-resultado-do-banco)

Comment: Não basta fazer `'value' => "D"` ou algo parecido?

Comment: Nossa, acho que é o cansaço kkk' é exatamente isso !
Eu estava tentando colocar `checked = 'D'` por isso não dava, obrigado Anderson, se quiser colocar a resposta, eu marco como correta !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme a [documentação](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-controls), basta definir o valor do atributo `value` para configurar qual elemento estará selecionado quando o formulário for renderizado.

Segue o trecho da documentação:

> 'value' - Sets or selects the value of the affected element(s)
>
> For radio buttons or select pickers it defines which element will be selected when the form is rendered (in this case 'value' must be assigned a valid, existent element value).

Se você deseja que o primeiro elemento esteja selecionado, basta definir o valor dele em `value`:

```
echo $this->Form->input('tipo', array(
     'type'   => 'radio',
     'before' => '<div ' . $style . '>',
     'separator' => '</div><div ' . $style . '>',
     'options' => array(
           'D' => $this->Html->image(
               "botoes/dinheiro.png", array(
                    "alt" => "Dinheiro", 
                    "title" => "Dinheiro", 
                    "style" => "height: 32px")),
           'P' => $this->Html->image(
               "botoes/porcento.png", array(
                    "alt" => "Porcentagem", 
                    "title" => "Porcentagem", 
                    "style" => "width: 28px")),
           'H' => $this->Html->image(
               "botoes/hora.png", array(
                    "alt" => "Hora", 
                    "title" => "Hora", 
                    "style" => "height: 32px"))),
     'id' => 'tipo', 
     'label' => 'Dinheiro/Porcento', 
     'style' => '', 
     'legend' => false, 
     'onclick' => "formular()", 
     'value' => 'D',                  // <===
     'required'));
```